# Android Web Kit and How to use Web Kit?

Tags: android, ios

I have one question in mind for "WEBKIT". What Is WebKit? What Is Android WebKit and How It is Differ From IOS WEbKit??How to use WebKit?
Want perfect and clear Answers.Anybody any idea ??

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit):

> WebKit is a layout engine software component designed to allow web
>   browsers to render web pages. It powers Apple's Safari web browser and
>   Google's Chrome web browser versions up to 27

So you can't *use WebKit* as such, as it is just a layout engine. You need to use a browser which uses WebKit as its base. Both iOS Safari and the Android Browser/(Certain versions of)Chrome use WebKit as its base so you need to use those.

Comment: Can You say When OR in which case we should Go for webKit ?? Is there any alternative to this.. actually i dont hav any idea regarding this.

Comment: The point is you can't *go for webkit*, you have no choice. As far as Android and iOS go, you can only use a WebKit-based browser right now.